# How to convert the expression 3*x to a function in Mathematica?

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

In doing a program in Mathematica that receives an expression called f and converts it to a function. However the command Function[x,f] doesn't work, what do I do?

Comment: Can you post the code you wrote, and what the desired output is that you want ?

Comment: @image_doctor I'm sorry to see that you deleted your entire answer. :-/

Comment: In the future, considering posting mathematica related stuff at mathematica.stackexchange.com . Ensure that you provide a minimum working code `:)`

Answer (score 1):

The function

```
f[x_]:=3*x
```

should do what you want. Then, to evaluate it:

[image: Mathematica graphics]